# Inertia ProgessBar show under Appbar React MUI

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

i have inertia progress bar initialized in my app.js

**app.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props }) {
    render(<App {...props} />, el);
  },
});

InertiaProgress.init({    
    // The color of the progress bar.
    color: "red",

    // Whether the NProgress spinner will be shown.
    showSpinner: true,
});
```

but the progressbar won't appear every time I render the appbar in the layout, its only the layout file, because if I render without it The progressbar will appear as usual

here is my **Layout.tsx**

```js
import {
    Button,
    Container,
    ListItem,
    ListItemIcon,
    ListItemText,
    useTheme,
} from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { styled, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import MuiDrawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import MuiAppBar, { AppBarProps as MuiAppBarProps } from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft";

import { listItems } from "./ListItems";
import { usePage } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import route from "ziggy-js";
import FlashMessage from "./FlashMessage";
import { withStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const Layout = ({
    children,
    title,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    title: React.ReactNode;    
}) => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    const authUser: any = usePage().props.user;
    const drawerWidth: number = 240;

    interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
        open?: boolean;
    }
    
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    const handleLogout = () => {
        if (confirm("are you sure want to logout?")) {
            Inertia.post(route("logout"));
        }
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <AppBar position="absolute" open={open}>
                    <Toolbar
                        sx={{
                            pr: "24px", // keep right padding when drawer closed
                        }}
                    >
                        <IconButton
                            edge="start"
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                            onClick={toggleDrawer}
                            sx={{
                                marginRight: "36px",
                                ...(open && { display: "none" }),
                            }}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography
                            component="h1"
                            variant="h6"
                            color="inherit"
                            noWrap
                            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, marginLeft: 2 }}
                        >
                            {title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Button
                            {...(authUser ? { display: "none" } : { sx: {} })}
                            variant="text"
                            color="inherit"
                            onClick={handleLogout}
                        >
                            Logout
                        </Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
                    <Toolbar
                        sx={{
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "flex-end",
                            px: [1],
                        }}
                    >
                        <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
                            <ChevronLeftIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Toolbar>
                    <Divider />
                    <List>{listItems}</List>
                </Drawer>
                <Box
                    component="main"                    
                    }}
                >
                    <Toolbar />
                    <FlashMessage />
                    <Container sx={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>{children}</Container>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

I think my progressbar appears under the appbar, is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find out what the zIndex for your AppBar is (1100 by default I think)

```
console.log(Theme.zIndex.appBar)
```

Then on your CSS file, add a line to make the zIndex of the progress bar higher:

```
#nprogress .bar {
    z-index: 1101!important;
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, thanks for the answer I already did it upvoted!